# Somehow, I'm getting the equation of a plane when setting equal the equations of two other, non-parallel planes

Tags: calculus, geometry

Say we have the planes $-6(x - 20) + 18(y - 15) + 16(z - 13) = 0$ and $13(x - 23) - 8(y - 15) + 24(z - 1) = 0$. These planes are not parallel to one another, and must thus intersect along a single line.

Setting the left sides of the equations equal to one another is like saying: "If I can find an $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that these two things equal one another, then I've found a point that lies on *both* planes," right?

When I do that, after simplifying, I get $6x - 7y - 4z = -81$ ... which is just the equation of a whole different plane. Since I got this equation by setting the above two plane equations equal to one another, that would mean that the set of points which lie on both of the above planes is itself a plane. But these two planes aren't parallel (they aren't the same plane), so how could that be?

Answer (score 4):

So I think I've found my mistake:

When we set the left side of each equation equal to one another, we *are*, in some way, getting a set of points that satisfy both equations—but we lose the constraint that each of these equations must be equal to $0$. We're effectively solving for the intersections of an infinite number of planes (an infinite number of lines... which make a plane!)

That is, we're also solving for 
$$-6(x - 20) + 18(y - 15) + 16(z - 13) = 1\\
13(x - 23) - 8(y - 15) + 24(z - 1) = 1$$

and

$$-6(x - 20) + 18(y - 15) + 16(z - 13) = 2\\
13(x - 23) - 8(y - 15) + 24(z - 1) = 2$$

and

$$-6(x - 20) + 18(y - 15) + 16(z - 13) = 0.5\\
13(x - 23) - 8(y - 15) + 24(z - 1) = 0.5$$

... etc.

So to re-implement that constraint, we can use the derived plane equation, solve for $x$ (or whichever variable), and plug that into one of the original equations which is set to equal $0$, giving us a line.

Answer (score 1):

Any equation reduces the dimension of the coordinates space (q.e. the number of variables) by one. Having 2 equations in 3 variables makes a 1-dimensional solution space. But when you replace 2 equations by a single one only, you would have a 2-dimensional solution space again.

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

You’ve run into an important caveat that came up recently in another question: the solutions to a system of equations also satisfy derived equations, but not, in general, vice-versa. This shouldn’t really be surprising. After all, there are probably solutions to the individual equations in the original system that don’t satisfy the system as a whole. The plane described by the new equation contains the original intersection line, but it also contains other points. (Indeed, every nonzero linear combination of the original two equations is that of a plane that passes through this line.)

The geometric intuition in your own answer is spot-on. You’ve removed the constraint that the points must lie on both planes—to put it differently, that their distances from the planes are both zero—and replaced it with the constraint that their (signed) distances to the two planes have a constant proportion.